# Show distinct values if column X is not null

Tags: sql

I need to select rows with distinct ID value but selected row should have DOB value that is not NULL if it exists. If not, then just select row with NULL DOB (example below with ID = 2).

```
ID   First_Name    Last_Name   DOB
1    John          Smith       1/1/1990
1    John          Smith       NULL
2    Jane          Doe         NULL
3    Martin        Schultz     NULL
3    Martin        Schultz     12/10/1976
3    Martin        Schultz     NULL
```

Comment: Is this data all from one table? What DBMS are you using?

Comment: Please leave your sample data as _text_...it's much easier to work with it that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aggregate by `ID` and names, then select the max value for the date of birth:

```sql
SELECT ID, First_Name, Last_Name, MAX(DOB) AS DOB
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY ID, First_Name, Last_Name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is `row_number()`

```
SELECT * FROM
(Select ID, First_Name,    Last_Name,   DOB
 row_number() over (PARTITION BY 
 ID, First_Name,    Last_Name
 ORDER BY 
 CASE WHEN DOB IS NOT NULL
 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END DESC) RN 
 from
 TABLE) WHERE RN =1;
```

Comment: Beware, `row_number()` and window-functions `over (PARTITION BY .. ORDER BY ..)` are DBMS-specific and may not supported on all databases.

Comment: But in most cases, its supported noones using a outdated version for their business usecase. This approach is performance wise better than a group by